# Get value from mySql into Php Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to: get all users by using the query in the below script into an array

Looking to get output like this:

```
$existing_users=array('value','value','value', 'value'...)
```

Php Script:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../inc/db/dbc.php');
$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Cant Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$q = mysql_query("SELECT uUName FROM User");

$existing_users=array(
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_NUM)) { 
        echo " '$row'.','";
    }
);

// $existing_users=array('joe','warren','tim'); 
# ^^^^ manual way of doing it

//value got from the get metho
$user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
//checking weather user exists or not in $existing_users array
if (in_array($user_name, $existing_users))
{
    //user name is not availble
    echo "no";
} 
else
{
    //user name is available
    echo "yes";
}
?>
```

How do I accomplish this? I know my while/array formation is a bit off there, how do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to check if the username is available, you can make a select like this: `SELECT uUName FROM User WHERE uUName = '$user_name';` If the select has data, the username is not available. Of course, you have to validate your input data first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$existing_users = Array();

while(list($username) = mysql_fetch_row($q)) $existing_users[] = $username;
```

`mysql_fetch_row($q)` will give you `Array(0 => result:uUName)`

so `list($xxx) = mysql_fetch_row($q)` - $xxx is first element of Array(0 => result:uUName) equals your `result:uUName`.